# how can i add fb like button for my website product?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, facebook-like

**I need to add facebook like button for my website for user like my product and that like product image post on their profile. I try many example but with that use only like website page not like product, and also post image of my website logo. i need to post my product image**

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="allowTransparency" width="280" height="65" src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?width=280&show_faces=0&layout=standard&href=http://www.websoite.com/newsite/webemp_02/facetsjewel/Productdetails/Art%20and%20Soul%20Fearless%20Bracelet"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you give the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="allowTransparency" width="280" height="65" src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?width=280&show_faces=0&layout=standard&href=http://www.websoite.com/newsite/webemp_02/facetsjewel/Productdetails/Art%20and%20Soul%20Fearless%20Bracelet"></iframe>

Comment: Place it with you code.

Comment: You have to pass your particular product single page URL to the iframe

Comment: Yes, This is my single  page url for product this product

Comment: Place your i frame code with your question, we cant see it full.

Comment: Go to the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button and add your particular product page URL to the `URL to Like` field, then try to customize it for all your products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use the exact same code as the one you get in the Like Button generator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Two problems with your code right now:

- You are trying to use an URL with whitespace. You should never do that. (%20 is whitespace)
- You did not urlencode the URL. Just put it in the generator and it will create the urlencoded version for you.

Try to open the link in the browser and you will see that it does not work: http://www.websoite.com/newsite/webemp_02/facetsjewel/Productdetails/Art%20and%20Soul%20Fearless%20Bracelet

You have to use a valid and public URL. If you use the generator, you get the following code - but you REALLY should not use whitespace in an URL:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oceanstechnologies.com%2Fnewsite%2Fwebemp_02%2Ffacetsjewel%2FProductdetails%2FArt%2520and%2520Soul%2520Fearless%2520Bracelet&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=1562584003953128" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

In order to get the correct image and text, make sure to include the necessary Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/

Comment: my original url was    http://www.oceanstechnologies.com/newsite/webemp_02/facetsjewel/Productdetails/Art%20and%20Soul%20Fearless%20Bracelet

Comment: as i said, that url includes whitespace. you can´t use whitespace in an url. i mean, you really shouldn´t. and i get a "database error" if i open that url. so it can never work with the like button.

Comment: ...and you did not use the generator for it, because else the url would be encoded (slashes and stuff).

Comment: you open again url link

Comment: it works now, but you REALLY should not use whitespace in URLs, that´s just...wrong

Comment: I need to replace my site logo with product image and also change title of post. i also i don't need post user comment below like link

Comment: i´ve added more information in the answer. about the comments: you can´t disable that.

Comment: i know in url not use whitespace but client need to this type of url.

Answer (score 1):

You can add share this plugin to your website http://www.sharethis.com which will integrate all the like buttons to your website like fb,twitter etc..You need to add some scripts in header and then need to add a  tag to your site on where you want to display like buttons..

Another option is You need to go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button link through your fb account..then you can generate the fb like button you want..They will give you some iframe code..Just integrate that code to your webpage.

Thanks.

Comment: I need like button not need share button

Comment: Then go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button  link and generate like button code